# Insert Text from Textbox Into Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to add the values / the text the user input from my textboxs into my database.

At the moment I can't get the code to insert the values to the sqldatabase.

Here is my aspx Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_WineName" runat="server" PlaceHolder="WineName" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_WineYear" runat="server" PlaceHolder="WineYear" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_WinePrice" runat="server" PlaceHolder="WinePrice" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_WineType" runat="server" PlaceHolder="WineType" />
<asp:Button ID="btn_AddWine" runat="server" Text="Add" />
```

Here is my C# code:

```
protected void btn_AddWine(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCM13812;Initial Catalog=Kronhjorten;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Wines";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        { 
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read()) 
                {
                    string Name = txt_WineName.Text;
                    string Year = txt_WineYear.Text;
                    string Price = txt_WinePrice.Text;
                    string Type = txt_WineType.Text;
                    Sql_Insert.Insert();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried other links from stackoverflow but can't seem to find anything that makes this work.

Hope you can help me. I'm sorry if I'm doing this in a strange way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The right commands:

First of all, you're using a `SqlDataReader`. This is not used for inserting data into a database but for reading data from it. You have to execute the `SqlCommand` you are using.

```
string query = "YOUR_QUERY_HERE";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCM13812;Initial Catalog=Kronhjorten;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open(); 
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

### Correct query:

When you get this right it's time to write a correct query. Yours starts with `SELECT`, again this is for retrieving data, not inserting. Your query should use `INSERT` and should look something like this:

```
string name = txt_WineName.Text;
string year = txt_WineYear.Text;
string price = txt_WinePrice.Text;
string type = txt_WineType.Text;

string query = "INSERT INTO Wines(Name, Year, Price, Type) " +
               "Values('" + name + "', '" + year + "', '" + price + "', '" + type + "')";
```

### Parameters/validation:

The code I presented is only meant as a demo, not as working code. You should always validate user input and use parameterized queries. More info/reading:

- [**Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)
- [**MSDN: SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [**SQL INSERT INTO**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SqlDataReader` which is only to read data from database not to insert/update.
Following links may help you

[Insert Data into database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389803/insert-data-into-database-in-c-sharp)

and

[How to insert Records in Database using C# language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142806/how-to-insert-records-in-database-using-c-sharp-language)