# My data is not saved on ms sql

Tags: c#

I just start learning programming and am trying to input data to sql table however, No data is inputted to ms sql for my code in C#, heres my code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DIT-NB1625963\\DIT1625963;" +
                        "database=ApplicationDevelopmentDB;" +
                        "integrated security=true";
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO game_table (PlayerScore, DealerScore)" +
                        "Values (23,21) ";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        richTextBox1.Text = "You have created a new record." + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        richTextBox1.Text = "Something wrong has occurred." + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine("Closed the connection");
                    }
                }



            }
        }
```

Comment: I bet the error message is "Something wrong has occurred."

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Hahahah @Plutonix  love question without the actuall error :D

Comment: Do a` try{} Catch(Exception ex) {throw ex}` trace it and see whats the ex's value

Comment: ...or just read the console output

Comment: @Valkyriee you should never do `throw ex;`, you should just do `throw;` if you do include the `ex` it resets the stack trace on you. Also to Jason, you will get a lot more useful information by doing `ex.ToString()` instead of just `ex.Message` you may want to print that to the console instead.

Comment: Not solution but you can remove `conn.Close();` if you are using `using` statement as it close and dispose connection as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142806/how-to-insert-records-in-database-using-c-sharp-language

Comment: heres the error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'game_table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: one of the fields has auto increment, can you check column properties?

Comment: yes my PlayerScore column has auto increment

Comment: If that field has autoincrement, value will be set automatically 1,2,3,4...N, so db engine is not expecting you to pass the value in the insert statement, typically we omit field name and value

Comment: `INSERT INTO game_table (PlayerScore, DealerScore) VALUES ...` where `PlayerScore` is an identity column obviously fails. I suggest you using third column which serves as autoincrement or just use single column instead: `INSERT INTO game_table (DealerScore) VALUES ...`