# I can't add records to the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, t-sql

I am working on an app and I got stuck in this problem. I am trying to add a record to my SQL local database. It gives the successful message box but when I close the app and check the table the record is not there. I tried adding it in two different ways and none of them worked. I will post the code here

Here is the first method that I tried

```
using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Restaurant.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Chelneri(username, nume, prenume, email, parola) values ('" + textBoxUser.Text.ToString().Trim() +"', '"+ textBoxNume.Text.ToString().Trim() +"', '"+ textBoxPrenume.Text.ToString().Trim() +"', '"+ textBoxEmail.Text.ToString().Trim() +"', '"+ textBoxParola.Text.ToString().Trim() +"')", _conn))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _conn.Open();
                            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            _conn.Close();
                            textBoxUser.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxNume.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxPrenume.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxParola.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxEmail.Text = string.Empty;
                            MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost creat!", "Restaurant Casa Verde", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Restaurant Casa Verde", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            _conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And here is the second one.

```
using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Restaurant.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Chelneri(username, nume, prenume, email, parola) values (@user, @nume, @prenume, @email, @parola)", _conn))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _conn.Open();

                            _cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxUser.Text.ToString().Trim();
                            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxEmail.Text.ToString().Trim();
                            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@nume", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxNume.Text.ToString().Trim();
                            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@prenume", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxPrenume.Text.ToString().Trim();
                            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@parola", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxParola.Text.ToString().Trim();

                            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            _conn.Close();
                            textBoxUser.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxNume.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxPrenume.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxParola.Text = string.Empty;
                            textBoxEmail.Text = string.Empty;
                            MessageBox.Show("Utilizatorul a fost creat!", "Restaurant Casa Verde", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Restaurant Casa Verde", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            _conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I don't think the code is the problem. I think that I am missing something and I don't know what.
Here is a printscreen of the database.
[image]

Comment: I suppose you don't get any errors, do you? I also see no transactions. So if the insert doesn't throw, the record should be created. It may sound dumb, but have you verified you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Furthermore, when you are using the `SqlConnection` with a `using` clause` you don't need to manually close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi I think your connection string is wrong 
first read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database/10480011) for get true connection string from your sql server 
second read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142806/how-to-insert-records-in-database-using-c-sharp-language) for true code for insert in database in C#

and I suggest use try catch like this

```
try
  {

  }
catch
  {

  }
finally { cnn.close}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Yep. The connection string was the problem. Visual Studio is creating two sets of databases, one in the actual project folder, and one in the debug folder. I was adding records to the debug database and I was checking the other one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine, but you are missing a simple touch check-in **Restaurant.mdf** is moving with your application, if not do this steps:

1. Right-click on **Restaurant.mdf** and click properties.
2. build options -> select if newer.

And also make sure that you are checking the correct database file.

If you run on debug mode, go to Bin\Debug folder and check the mdf file in there, if you run on release mode you need to check on Bin\Release folder.

Source : [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/838662/insert-into-mdf-database)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I was checking the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "`using`", you don't need `_cmd.Close()`;